# Repeated routes with React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Is a good way to repeat routes in the nested components?

```
<App>
   <Route exact path="/" render={props =>
      <Layout>
         <Route exact path="/" component={ComponentUnderLayout} />
         <Route exact path="/path1" component={ComponentUnderLayout2} /> 
      </Layout>
   } />
   <Route path="/signin" component={ComponentWithoutLayout} />
</App>
```

I'm not sure that it's the best solution. As you can see I'm going to wrap all components of my app except some of them. I want to render Layout and Header for all paths except /signin and /signup.

Maybe are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things I'm concerned about your code: 1. Render is a function:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props =>
   <Layout>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ComponentUnderLayout} />
      <Route exact path="/path1" component={ComponentUnderLayout2} /> 
   </Layout>
} />
```

2. `ComponentUnderLayout2` will never get rendered:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props =>
   {/* you have declared that this will get render ONLY when URL is exactly ` "/" which means "/path1" will never get to this place */}
   <Layout>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ComponentUnderLayout} />
      <Route exact path="/path1" component={ComponentUnderLayout2} /> 
   </Layout>
} />
```

So if you correct above you'll end up with:

```
<App>
   <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => 
      <Layout>
         <ComponentUnderLayout {...props} />
      </Layout>
   } />
   <Route path="/path1" render={props => 
      <Layout>
         <ComponentUnderLayout2 {...props} />
      </Layout>
   } /> 
   <Route path="/signin" component={ComponentWithoutLayout} />
</App>
```

EDIT:

```
<App>
   <Layout>
     <Route exact path="/" component={ComponentUnderLayout} />
     <Route exact path="/path1" component={ComponentUnderLayout2} />
   </Layout>
   <Route exact path="/signin" component={ComponentWithoutLayout} />
</App>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I get what you mean, but I have to duplicate a lot of code in this case. I'm trying to render `Header` and `Layout` for all paths except _/signin_ and _/signup_.

Comment: Can't you do something like in the EDIT?

Comment: I think Layout is rendered above `ComponentWithoutLayout` in this case.